# OUTER APPLY is not supported in this LINQ query

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

I need to run this query in a oracle 11.2 database, but the generated query contains a "OUTER APPLY". How can I solve it ?

```
var query = from r in Ctx.Reg
    let status_1 = (r.Hist.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).FirstOrDefault(h => h.RegId == r.Id).Status == 1)
    let status_2 = (r.Hist.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(h => h.RegId == r.Id).Status == 2)
    select new
    {
        r.Id,
        ...
        status_1,
        status_2
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OUTER APPLY` is generated by your `let` statement expressions. You can avoid it by turning them into `EXISTS` translatable expressions using the equivalent `Any` based LINQ constructs:

```
var query = from r in Ctx.Reg
    let status_1 = r.Hist.OrderByDescending(h => h.Id).Take(1).Any(h => h.Status == 1)
    let status_2 = r.Hist.OrderByDescending(h => h.Id).Skip(1).Take(1).Any(h => h.Status == 2)
    select new
    {
        r.Id,
        ...
        status_1,
        status_2
    };
```

Note that `h.RegId == r.Id` is not needed because that is implied by `r.Hist` navigation property.